# Дискорд Бот не отвечает на команду

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я хотел сделать бота для Дискорд, который отправляет рандомную картинку с определённого сабреддита(в данном случае с r/memes), но при вводе команды - *тишина*[image: бот не отвечает]

Код:

```
import praw
import random
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "token :)"

bot = commands.Bot(description="test", command_prefix="$")
bot.remove_command( 'help' )

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='ID :)',
                     client_secret='Secret :)',
                     user_agent='MyBot')

@bot.command()
async def meme():
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await bot.say(submission.url)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Терминал выводит при эту ошибку после отправки команды на сервере:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 690, in _parse_arguments
    next(iterator)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 976, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 693, in _parse_arguments
    raise discord.ClientException(fmt.format(self))
discord.errors.ClientException: Callback for meme command is missing "ctx" parameter.
```

Я не понимаю с чем это связано. Я - новичок в Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерпретатор сообщает вам, что у функции `meme()` упущен аргумент `ctx`.

`ctx` - Контекст выполнения команды, содержащий информацию о сервере, пользователе и [**другую информацию**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)

Этот аргумент в вашу функцию передает `discord`, при вызове команды, однако ваша функция не принимает аргументов.

Чтобы не возникало ошибки, достаточно просто добавить в функцию принятие аргумента:

```
async def meme(ctx):
```

---

Ну и насколько мне известно, у объекта `commands.Bot` нет функции `say()`. Если вы хотите отправить сообщение, в канал, где была вызвана команда, то можете как раз таки воспользоваться контекстом:

```
await ctx.send(submission.url)
```